# How to apply opcodes optimization directly on opcodes? Solidity compiler

Tags: optimization, ethereum, solidity, evm, solc

According to [documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/internals/optimizer.html#opcode-based-optimizer-module), one of the steps of solidity compilation is the optimization on opcodes level, with the following [set of rules](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/blob/develop/libevmasm/RuleList.h).
How can I apply optimization directly on opcodes?

**Details**
Let's say I compiled a contract with the `--opcodes` option and opcodes optimization disabled:

```
solc --opcodes --evm-version shanghai example_contract.sol
```

Resulting in opcodes, like this:

```
PUSH1 0x80 PUSH1 0x40 MSTORE CALLVALUE DUP1 ISZERO PUSH2 0xF JUMPI PUSH0 DUP1 REVERT JUMPDEST POP PUSH1 0x40 ...
```

I want to optimize it on the opcodes level for 200 runs, to get the result, same as the output of:

```
solc --opcodes --evm-version shanghai --optimize --optimizate-runs 200 example_contract.sol
```

The **goal** is the augmentation of the dataset with opcodes representation of smart contracts with different optimization parameters for non-verified smart contracts, so **I don't have access to the source code**.